# array of signals in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl

i'm trying to define a 4096*16 RAM, i did like this:

```
entity Test is
port(
...
IR : inout std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
AR : inout std_logic_vector(11 downto 0));
end test

architecture test1 of test is
    type ram is array(4095 downto 0) of std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        signal ram1 : ram := (others => (others => '0'));
begin
AR <= "000000000000";
    ram1(0) <= "0010000000000100";
...
...
process(arguments)
    IR <= ram1(conv_integer(AR));
```

my problem is, when i give ram1 values, and then give ram1 values to an output port, its ones (1s) become Unknown (X)  in Isim

i get  "00X000000X00" for IR in isim

Comment: you should post a simplified version of your VHDL code which reproduces the problem. It's difficult to tell where the problem is with the given information. `X` in ISim means 'unknown value'. Do you assign and read the value in the same clock cycle ? That may violate [setup and hold time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_timing_analysis) constraints.

Comment: is this clear now, i edited my code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a synchronous design for your RAM entity:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
USE ieee.numeric_std.ALL; 

entity Test is
port(
  clock : in std_logic;                      -- clock
  IR : inout std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);  -- data port
  AR : in    std_logic_vector(11 downto 0);  -- address port
  write_enable : in  std_logic               -- '1' -> write, '0' -> read

  );
end test;

architecture test1 of Test is
    type ram is array(0 to 4095) of std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);

    -- the actual ram
    signal ram1 : ram := (others => (others => '0'));

    -- internal signal for reading data
    signal IR_out : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0) := (others => 'Z');

begin

-- only apply our own signal to the data port
-- during read
IR <= IR_out when write_enable = '0' else (others => 'Z');

proc: process(clock) is
begin

  if rising_edge(clock) then
    if write_enable = '1' then

      -- write to RAM
      ram1(to_integer(unsigned(AR))) <= IR;

    else
      -- read from RAM
      IR_out <= ram1(to_integer(unsigned(AR)));      

    end if;

  end if; -- rising edge

end process;

end; -- architecture
```

and here is a testbench for it:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity Testbench is 
end Testbench;

architecture TB of Testbench is

   component Test
     port(
       clock : in std_logic;                      -- clock
       IR : inout std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);  -- data port
       AR : in    std_logic_vector(11 downto 0);   -- address port
       write_enable : in  std_logic              -- '1' -> write, '0' -> read
    );
   end component;

   -- define signals
   signal clock : std_logic := '0';

   -- our internal signals
   signal IRtest            : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0) := (others => 'Z');
   signal ARtest            : std_logic_vector(11 downto 0) := (others => '0');
   signal write_enable_test : std_logic := '0';

begin

   -- Instantiate a RAM to be tested and connect it to our signals
   uut: Test PORT MAP (
         clock        => clock,
         AR           => ARtest,
         IR           => IRtest,
         write_enable => write_enable_test
         );      

   -- clock generator (10 MHz)
   clockgen : process
   begin
     clock <= '0';
     wait for 50ns;
     clock <= '1';
     wait for 50ns;
   end process;

   -- generate signals to test the RAM
   stimulus : process
   begin        

     -- write data into ram
     ARtest <= "000000000000";
     IRtest <= "0010000000000100";
     write_enable_test <= '1';

     wait for 100 ns;

     -- read a different address back from RAM
     ARtest <= "000000000001";
     IRtest <= (others => 'Z');
     write_enable_test <= '0';
     wait for 100 ns;

     -- read the original address back from ram
     ARtest <= "000000000000";
     IRtest <= (others => 'Z');
     write_enable_test <= '0';
     wait for 100 ns;

     wait;


end process;


end; -- architecture
```

The testbench essentially writes the value to the RAM in the first clock cycle, reads a different address in the second clock cycle and then reads the contents of the original address in the third clock cycle.

The waveform output for the testbench is:

[image: waveform output of vhdl simulator]

Note that you'll get the contents of the ram at the output port of the RAM entity only on the next rising edge of the clock cycle.

You can fiddle with the design and testbench here: http://www.edaplayground.com/x/5w8

I saw also an asynchronous (not using `if rising_edge(clock)`) example here: http://www.edaplayground.com/x/3Zs

Answer (score 0):

When using ISim, I assume you use Xilinx FPGA.  In that case, take a looks at the [Xilinx, HDL Coding Practices](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/white_papers/wp231.pdf) for inferring different kind of elements, e.g. RAMs.

Also, only use `inout` at the toplevel of the design, and even if the RAM is at the top level, then separate the `inout` from the RAM, so the synthesis tool can implement the different parts of the design, like IO elements and RAMs, correctly.

An example of coding style for inferred RAM, based on the above paper, is:

```
process (clk)
begin
  if (rising_edge(clk)) then
    if (we = '1') then
      mem(conv_integer(addr)) <= di ;
    else
      do <= mem(conv_integer(addr));
    end if;
  end if;
end process;
```